# Regex to add a character at nth position?

Tags: regex, replace

I have this text:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

where I need to add character at fifth position to have this result

```
11111A11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

I tried with

```
(?<=.{5})
```

Replace with

```
A
```

it puts A after fifth character but continue to ad to every next five characters.

I am using Powergrep.
How to make it to stop after first occurence?

Comment: Not sure how powergrep works, but look into disabling its **global** mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `^` character to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regular expression to the start of the string:

```
(?<=^.{5})
```

See [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/bC6rF6/1)

Comment: It works, thanks. Any way to expand this, so it can add character A at 5th and 10th and 20th position? I tried (?<=^.{5,10,20}) but changes nothing.

Comment: In that case you cannot work with `(?<=`. Instead, capture the digits, and replace them back in with `\1` etc: `(^.{5})(.{5})(.{10})` => `\1A\2A\3A` (https://regex101.com/r/bC6rF6/3)