# Replace the nth index of a character

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace the nth index of a character using only Regex.

```
string input = "%fdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdffd";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "^%", "");
```

The above code, replaces the first character with an empty string, But, I want to specify an index: like nth index, so that character gets replaced with an empty string.

Can someone help me out here.

Comment: Also, that `^%` regex will always only have one match.

Comment: And why do you need to use regular expressions here?

Comment: Ya, But, now I need to specify in the Regex to remove a particular character index.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Home work. :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971945/replacing-the-nth-character-in-a-string-only-if-it-is-a-particular-character-in, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624383/regex-to-add-a-character-at-nth-position

Comment: regex is to search for patterns, not to get index-based characters.

Comment: Search `"^(.{7})."` and replace with `"$1"`. If *C#* supports [`\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) you could also use `"^.{7}\\K."` with replacement `""`. Or using a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) `"(?<=^.{7})."` with replacement `""`. I'm not sure if *C#* supports `\K`, or [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) inside a lookbehind though.

Comment: In your exact example, you could potentially use a positive lookbehind like this: `(?<=(fd){n})fd` where `n` is the number of matches you want to skip before replacing

Comment: "index" is usually used for a specific position within a string, independent of specific character. Do you maybe mean "the nth occurrence of" that character? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to create a regex pattern that captures all characters before and after the replaced character and then replace the whole string with the two captures separated by the new character. For example:

```
Regex.Replace("abcdefgh", @"^(.{4}).(.*)$", @"$1E$2") // returns "abcdEfgh"
```

You could then create a method that replaces the character at a specific index:

```
string ReplaceCharacter(string text, int index, char value)
    => Regex.Replace(text, $@"^(.{{{index}}}).(.*)$", $@"${{1}}{value}${{2}}");

// Usage:
ReplaceCharacter("Foo-bar", 3, 'l') // returns "Foolbar"
```

Answer (score 1):

As Johan Wentholt said in the comments, you can perfectly use `Regex.Replace` to match a number of characters from the start of the line and replace it with a capture group that's one character less than the full matched piece:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, "^(.{" + index + "}).", "$1");
```

This matches "`index` times any character, followed by another character, at the start of the string", but replaces it by only the "`index` times any character" without that last character, since that last dot is outside of the capture group.

If you want to replace by something else than an empty string, you just concatenate it to the end of the `"$1"` replacement string. Though to be safe then, you should replace it with `"${1}"` to avoid problems if the piece you add behind it starts with a number, since that would change the capture group number.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do may not be possible with Regex alone. This is sort of a cheat:

```
var input = "%fdfd678dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdffd";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, "^.{7}", input.Substring(0,6));

Console.WriteLine($"result = {result}");
```

Comment: It is possible with just regex, if you use a capture group.

Comment: yes, but you have to "concat" matched groups in some way. I wouldn't call it a "regex only" solution.

Comment: Not at all. Put a capture group in the regex that captures one less character than the whole matched expression, and replace that by the contents of the capture group, and you're done.